# How to use the Ninject xml config with TEntity?

Tags: ninject

This should work:-

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

where:-

`IRepository<>` is an interface of the form:-

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T :class 
{

     //...

}
```

`Repository<>` is a class of the form:-

```
public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T :class
{

    //...

}
```

But how to do it in XML configuration using Ninject.Extensions.Xml?

It does not work.

Comment: What XML configuration have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out what the name of the type is by doing `typeof(IRepository<>).FullName` and then configure the XML as follows:

```
<module name="myXmlConfigurationModule">
    <bind service="MyNamespace.IRepository`1, MyAssembly"
          to="MyNamespace.Repository`1, MyAssembly" />
</module>
```

I haven't used the XML extensions for Ninject before, but that *should* work